# iOS 11 navigationBar with both segmentedControl and searchBar

Tags: uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, ios11, uisearchcontroller

Looking into setting up a parentViewController with a `segmentedControl` to switch between two (or more) viewControllers, I found this excellent tutorial: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

I then added `UITableViewController` as one of the childViewControllers.

So far so good.

Then I added a `UISearchController` and added the `searchBar` as recommended by Apple:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

But because there is already a `UISegmentedControl` in the `navigationBar` (set up in the storyBoard), the `searchBar` doesn't show up. I can fall back to the pre iOS 11 method, and the `searchBar` is now visible in the `tableView` header, but of course it doesn't have the iOS 11 look anymore.

Is it possible to have both the `segmentedControl` and `searchBar` in the `navigationBar`?

EDIT:

I also tried using the `titleView` for the `segmentedControl`, but still, the `searchBar` does not show up.

One workaround may be to change the appearance of the iOS 10 `searchBar`, but that would still not feel right.